# Decomposition of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

If $K_n$ decomposes into triangles($K_3$) then find the values of $n$ ?

A decomposition of graph is a list of subgraphs such that each edge appears in exactly one of the subgraphs.

I have been able to solve it in one direction, that if $K_n$ decomposes into triangles then $ n \equiv 1 (mod \; 6)$ or $ n \equiv 3 (mod \; 6)$. But showing the sufficiency of the values was something where I faced trouble. How to show for all $ n = $  $ 6k + 1 $ and $ n = $ $6k + 5$,  $K_n$ has a decomposition into triangles.

Comment: This is equivalent to the existence of a Steiner triple system of these orders, whose proof you should be able to find online fairly easily (for instance, I found this slide show with a quick google search: http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m6406/sts.pdf (but you should be able to find better resources with a bit more effort)). I believe this was first proven by Kirkman in the mid-1800s.

Comment: Hi, the question does not ask for a sufficient condition, only a necessary one : if there is a decomposition **then** $n=$ *something*, but not the reverse.